# Extending Curses Rectangle Box to edge of Terminal in Python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, python-curses

I'm having some trouble with creating a rectangle in Curses using Python.

This is my code:

```
import curses
from curses.textpad import Textbox, rectangle

def draw_menu(stdscr):

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()

    while True:
        stdscr.refresh()


        writebox_uly = (int(stdscr.getbegyx()[0]))
        writebox_ulx = (int(stdscr.getbegyx()[1]))
        writebox_lry = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[0] * 0.7))
        writebox_lrx = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[1] - 1))

        rectangle(stdscr, writebox_uly, writebox_ulx, writebox_lry, writebox_lrx)

        editwin_uly = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[0] * 0.7 + 1))
        editwin_ulx = (int(stdscr.getbegyx()[1]))
        editwin_lry = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[0] - 1))
        editwin_lrx = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[1] - 2))

        rectangle(stdscr, editwin_uly, editwin_ulx, editwin_lry, editwin_lrx)

def main():
    curses.wrapper(draw_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This creates two nice rectangles, like this picture below:
[image: Two rectangles]

You might notice that the bottom right corner of the lower box is not inline. This is because of `editwin_lrx = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[1] - 2))`

This line sets the Lower Right X coordinate (The bottom right corner) equal to the maximum width of the Terminal, minus 2

Changing this to `editwin_lrx = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[1] - 5))` Will bring the box much further to the left.

[image: Two more rectangles]

so, theoretically, changing it to `editwin_lrx = (int(stdscr.getmaxyx()[1] - 1))` will push it slightly further to the right.

But it doesn't it crashes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "temp.py", line 29, in main
    curses.wrapper(draw_menu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "temp.py", line 26, in draw_menu
    rectangle(stdscr, editwin_uly, editwin_ulx, editwin_lry, editwin_lrx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/textpad.py", line 16, in rectangle
    win.addch(lry, lrx, curses.ACS_LRCORNER)
_curses.error: addch() returned ERR
```

Is it possible to extend the second box's right side to the very edge, bringing it inline with the first box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to catch the exception and ignore it.  The **`rectangle`** function looks like this:

```
def rectangle(win, uly, ulx, lry, lrx):                                         
    """Draw a rectangle with corners at the provided upper-left                 
    and lower-right coordinates.                                                
    """                                                                         
    win.vline(uly+1, ulx, curses.ACS_VLINE, lry - uly - 1)                      
    win.hline(uly, ulx+1, curses.ACS_HLINE, lrx - ulx - 1)                      
    win.hline(lry, ulx+1, curses.ACS_HLINE, lrx - ulx - 1)                      
    win.vline(uly+1, lrx, curses.ACS_VLINE, lry - uly - 1)                      
    win.addch(uly, ulx, curses.ACS_ULCORNER)                                    
    win.addch(uly, lrx, curses.ACS_URCORNER)                                    
    win.addch(lry, lrx, curses.ACS_LRCORNER)                                    
    win.addch(lry, ulx, curses.ACS_LLCORNER)
```

As documented in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters), curses returns an error (which **`rectangle`** should have ignored) when writing to the lower-right corner of the screen:

> - At  the  bottom of the current scrolling region, and if scrollok is
>            enabled, the scrolling region is scrolled up one line.
> - If scrollok is not enabled, writing a character at the lower  right
>            margin  succeeds.   However, an ***error*** is returned because it is not
>            possible to wrap to a new line

Comment: no problem.  Actually the **`box`** function should work without having to capture the exception...